# how can I accelerate scroll speed of the browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, scroll

I am looking for a way to scroll the browser with an accelerated speed that runs in line of an elevator. For now all I can find is all the easing effects but none of them I can add acceleration. Below is the code I wrote.

```js
  var evenSpeed = 5.8;
  $("html, body").animate( 
    {scrollTop: $("html, body").offset().top +"px"
    },{
      duration: document.body.scrollTop/evenSpeed,   
      easing: "linear"} 
  );
```

Comment: see my answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function wheel(event) {
      var delta = 0;
      if (event.wheelDelta) {(delta = event.wheelDelta / 30);}
      else if (event.detail) {(delta = -event.detail / 3);}

      handle(delta);
      if (event.preventDefault) {(event.preventDefault());}
      event.returnValue = false;
  }

  function handle(delta) {
      var time = 1000;
      var distance = 300;

      $('html, body').stop().animate({
          scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() - (distance * delta)
      }, time );
  }

  if (window.addEventListener) {window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);}
    window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">
  Conoce la cartelera completa del evento UFC Fight Night 103, encabezada por una pelea entre Yaír Rodriguez y BJ Penn.
La UFC llevará acabo su primer cartelera del año este próximo 15 de Enero, esto con el evento UFC Fight Night 103 en la ciudad de Phoenix, Arizona.

Encabezando la cartelera tendremos una muy dinámica pelea, esto cuando Yaír Rodriguez vuelva a la acción para enfrentarse al miembro del salón de la fama BJ Penn. Mientras tanto el evento coestelar presentará una divertida pelea entre Joe Lauzon y Marcin Held.


¿Pero cómo luce el resto de la cartelera? Aquí los dejamos con el listado completo de peleas:
Conoce la cartelera completa del evento UFC Fight Night 103, encabezada por una pelea entre Yaír Rodriguez y BJ Penn.
La UFC llevará acabo su primer cartelera del año este próximo 15 de Enero, esto con el evento UFC Fight Night 103 en la ciudad de Phoenix, Arizona.

Encabezando la cartelera tendremos una muy dinámica pelea, esto cuando Yaír Rodriguez vuelva a la acción para enfrentarse al miembro del salón de la fama BJ Penn. Mientras tanto el evento coestelar presentará una divertida pelea entre Joe Lauzon y Marcin Held.


¿Pero cómo luce el resto de la cartelera? Aquí los dejamos con el listado completo de peleas:
Conoce la cartelera completa del evento UFC Fight Night 103, encabezada por una pelea entre Yaír Rodriguez y BJ Penn.
La UFC llevará acabo su primer cartelera del año este próximo 15 de Enero, esto con el evento UFC Fight Night 103 en la ciudad de Phoenix, Arizona.

Encabezando la cartelera tendremos una muy dinámica pelea, esto cuando Yaír Rodriguez vuelva a la acción para enfrentarse al miembro del salón de la fama BJ Penn. Mientras tanto el evento coestelar presentará una divertida pelea entre Joe Lauzon y Marcin Held.


¿Pero cómo luce el resto de la cartelera? Aquí los dejamos con el listado completo de peleas:
</div>
```

important: `event.wheelDelta / 120`